# How can I convert characters and string to a byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, character-encoding

Having trouble converting the characters into a string to get the bytes than use an array to send through serial port.

```
   const char STX = '\u0002';
   const char ETX = '\u0003';
   string pull_shelf_104 = ( STX + "01P00104##" + ETX);

   private byte[] WrapString(string pull_shelf_104)
   {
       int length = pull_shelf_104.Length;
       byte[] send104 = new byte[length];
       Array.Copy(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pull_shelf_104), 0, send104, 0, length);
       return send104;
   }

   private void linkLabel_HC1_100_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
       {
           byte data = WrapString(string pull_shelf_104);
           serialPort1.Write(data,0,1);
       }
   }
```

Comment: You don't need `Array.Copy` as `ASCII.GetBytes` already returns an array of bytes.

Comment: You said `Having trouble`, what is the trouble? Did you get any error?

Answer (score 3):

You can try simply:

```
private byte[] WrapString(string pull_shelf_104)
{
   return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pull_shelf_104);
}
```